# Examples of VQE on Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, resource-request, vqe

I'm a quantum beginner, and I really need some examples to help me understand quantum computing. In particular, how to get the ground energy of Hubbard or using model with VQE in Qiskit.

Code examples would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look to the following chapters in the Qiskit Textbook?

- Simulating Molecules using VQE:
  https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/vqe-molecules.html#vqe
- Variational Quantum Linear Solver:
  https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-paper-implementations/vqls.html

Comment: Of course, i already know that. but thank you.

Comment: Do you have some  codes written by yourself？@luciano